# Ошибка при компиляции kivy приложения в apk

Tags: python, python-3.x, компиляция, kivy, apk

после запуска "buildozer init"  потом "buildozer android debug"
выходит такая ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/home/egor/Kivy_test/untitled/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 1186, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/egor/Kivy_test/untitled/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 1180, in main
    ToolchainCL()
  File "/home/egor/Kivy_test/untitled/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 663, in __init__
    getattr(self, args.subparser_name.replace('-', '_'))(args)
  File "/home/egor/Kivy_test/untitled/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 152, in wrapper_func
    build_dist_from_args(ctx, dist, args)
  File "/home/egor/Kivy_test/untitled/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 205, in build_dist_from_args
    args, "ignore_setup_py", False
  File "/home/egor/Kivy_test/untitled/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/build.py", line 555, in build_recipes
    recipe.build_arch(arch)
  File "/home/egor/Kivy_test/untitled/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/recipes/libffi/__init__.py", line 33, in build_arch
    shprint(sh.Command('./autogen.sh'), _env=env)
  File "/home/egor/Kivy_test/untitled/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/logger.py", line 178, in shprint
    for line in output:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sh.py", line 863, in next
    self.wait()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sh.py", line 792, in wait
    self.handle_command_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sh.py", line 815, in handle_command_exit_code
    raise exc
sh.ErrorReturnCode_127: 

  RAN: /home/egor/Kivy_test/untitled/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/other_builds/libffi/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/libffi/autogen.sh

  STDOUT:
/home/egor/Kivy_test/untitled/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/other_builds/libffi/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/libffi/autogen.sh: 2: exec: autoreconf: not found


  STDERR:

# Command failed: /usr/bin/python3 -m pythonforandroid.toolchain create --dist_name=myapp --bootstrap=sdl2 --requirements=python3,kivy --arch armeabi-v7a --copy-libs --color=always --storage-dir="/home/egor/Kivy_test/untitled/.buildozer/android/platform/build" --ndk-api=21
# ENVIRONMENT:
#     CLUTTER_IM_MODULE = 'xim'
#     LS_COLORS = 'rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.wim=01;31:*.swm=01;31:*.dwm=01;31:*.esd=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:'
#     LESSCLOSE = '/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s'
#     XDG_MENU_PREFIX = 'gnome-'
#     LANG = 'ru_RU.UTF-8'
#     MANAGERPID = '1358'
#     DISPLAY = ':0'
#     INVOCATION_ID = 'b04e67da0c4047d8b215fb922678cbe4'
#     GNOME_SHELL_SESSION_MODE = 'ubuntu'
#     COLORTERM = 'truecolor'
#     USERNAME = 'egor'
#     XDG_VTNR = '2'
#     SSH_AUTH_SOCK = '/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh'
#     MANDATORY_PATH = '/usr/share/gconf/ubuntu.mandatory.path'
#     XDG_SESSION_ID = '2'
#     USER = 'egor'
#     DESKTOP_SESSION = 'ubuntu'
#     QT4_IM_MODULE = 'xim'
#     TEXTDOMAINDIR = '/usr/share/locale/'
#     GNOME_TERMINAL_SCREEN = '/org/gnome/Terminal/screen/426d81ca_1dda_462b_bbf9_4d7550832fed'
#     DEFAULTS_PATH = '/usr/share/gconf/ubuntu.default.path'
#     PWD = '/home/egor/Kivy_test/untitled'
#     HOME = '/home/egor'
#     JOURNAL_STREAM = '9:27469'
#     TEXTDOMAIN = 'im-config'
#     SSH_AGENT_PID = '1486'
#     QT_ACCESSIBILITY = '1'
#     XDG_SESSION_TYPE = 'x11'
#     XDG_DATA_DIRS = '/usr/share/ubuntu:/usr/local/share:/usr/share:/var/lib/snapd/desktop'
#     XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP = 'ubuntu'
#     DBUS_STARTER_ADDRESS = 'unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus,guid=64f88073108af24343d2c3f75d15f257'
#     GTK_MODULES = 'gail:atk-bridge'
#     WINDOWPATH = '2'
#     TERM = 'xterm-256color'
#     SHELL = '/bin/bash'
#     VTE_VERSION = '5202'
#     QT_IM_MODULE = 'ibus'
#     XMODIFIERS = '@im=ibus'
#     IM_CONFIG_PHASE = '2'
#     DBUS_STARTER_BUS_TYPE = 'session'
#     XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP = 'ubuntu:GNOME'
#     GPG_AGENT_INFO = '/run/user/1000/gnupg/S.gpg-agent:0:1'
#     GNOME_TERMINAL_SERVICE = ':1.224'
#     XDG_SEAT = 'seat0'
#     SHLVL = '1'
#     GDMSESSION = 'ubuntu'
#     GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID = 'this-is-deprecated'
#     LOGNAME = 'egor'
#     DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS = 'unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus,guid=64f88073108af24343d2c3f75d15f257'
#     XDG_RUNTIME_DIR = '/run/user/1000'
#     XAUTHORITY = '/run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority'
#     XDG_CONFIG_DIRS = '/etc/xdg/xdg-ubuntu:/etc/xdg'
#     PATH = '/home/egor/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin'
#     SESSION_MANAGER = 'local/Egor:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/1390,unix/Egor:/tmp/.ICE-unix/1390'
#     LESSOPEN = '| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s'
#     GTK_IM_MODULE = 'ibus'
#     _ = '/usr/local/bin/buildozer'
#     PACKAGES_PATH = '/home/egor/.buildozer/android/packages'
#     ANDROIDSDK = '/home/egor/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk'
#     ANDROIDNDK = '/home/egor/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r17c'
#     ANDROIDAPI = '27'
#     ANDROIDMINAPI = '21'
# 
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

Что делать?

Comment: Для начала показать свой .spec файл!

Comment: Ну, и правильно установить зависимости - https://github.com/HeaTTheatR/KivyMD#packages-for-android-are-built-according-to-the-following-instructions

Comment: Спасибо дело было в зависимостях!